# Hector_slam install fails; missing dependency opencv2

Tags: slam, navigation, beaglebone, opencv2, hector-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm doing an install on my BeagleBone and I get the following error:

```
Unable to locate package ros-groovy-opencv2
```

This indicates the binary is not available for the ARM/Beaglebone so I need to get opencv2 from source. I'm not finding an option for installing this from source.

I tried the full install of OpenCV but the error persists.

A) Did I need to install the full OpenCV?
B) Where can I find the source install for opencv2?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64459/hector_slam-install-fails;-missing-dependency-opencv2/) by [TJump](https://answers.ros.org/users/2785/tjump/) on ROS Answers with karma: 160 on 2013-06-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

OpenCV is actually only required because of hector_compressed_map_transport IIRC. So if you check out from source (and check out only the packages you really want to use) you should be able to get around the problem by just never calling "rosmake hector_compressed_map_transport" (either explicitly or implicitly).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2013-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TJump](https://answers.ros.org/users/2785/tjump/) on 2013-06-07**:
Okay; I got a successful install and build of hector_slam when I removed hector_compressed_map_transport. I'm not sure if this package will be needed to get maps to a remote location but will test without it for now.

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2013-06-07**:
It can be used but is definitely not needed.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You may find the OpenCV Github page useful:

https://github.com/itseez/opencv

There is also an installation guide on the OpenCV website: http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2013-06-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1